# Unable to add JSON into DOM via javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I am having a problem entering the text of the external JSON file into my DOM. I have used the alert command to confirm i was able to retrieve the data, now i cannot add the retrieved data into the DOM.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Starting Point</title>
<script>
function do_exercise () {
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open('GET', 'http://tmaserv.scem.uws.edu.au/chapters/?n=2', true);
    x.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (x.readyState == 4 && x.status ==200) {
            obj = (x.responseText);
            alert(obj);
            obj = JSON.parse(text);
            document.getElementById("section1").innerHTML =
            obj.map(function(chap) { 
            return chap.data}).join("<br />");
        }
    }

    x.send(null);
}
    </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <nav>           
            <button onclick="do_exercise();">Click Me</button>      
            </nav>
            <section id = "section1">
            <h1>Heading One</h1>
            <p>Paragraph One.</p>
            </section>
    </body>
```

Comment: Any error messages? console.log the returned data to see if it meets your expectations?

Comment: `obj = JSON.parse(text);` text variable doesn't exist.

Comment: as majed said i have an error obj = JSON.parse(text); and not getting any output

Answer (score -1, accepted):

first, wrong variable name...

```
obj = (x.responseText);
//obj = JSON.parse(text);
obj = JSON.parse(obj);
```

second, received data is an Object not an Array, so you can not use "map" method.

Comment: The object *may* be an Array.

Comment: changing the obj worked great, and ive only learnt the map method is there another method? and if i just do "obj.data" instead of the map method it will print it out

Comment: yeah, it just a friendly suggestion. cause if u want to use "map" method, you have to make sure obj is an Array. and if you want to make it work with Object data well, you can try tradition way: for (var key in obj){...}

Comment: @Ja͢ck i know it may be, but it may be not too. and i actually visited the link http://tmaserv.scem.uws.edu.au/chapters/?n=2, the result data was not an Array, and i got a error when i test the code.

Comment: Ah, you're right; I didn't bother to check the response ;-)

Comment: i just deleted the map function and just wrote obj.data. and another quick question if i wanted to change a specific word in the HTML file after getting it from JSON e.g. where it says type: paragraph and i want to change it to <p> i use an if statement?

Comment: @DOGGIES52 try this: `var html = '';for (var key in obj){switch(key){case "paragraph": html += '<p>' + obj[key] + '</p>';break;case "..." ...}}document.getElementById("section1").innerHTML = html;`